# Maven Compiler: Check syntax for Java version

Tags: java, maven

I have a question of understanding:

Suppose I have Java code and use Java 11 syntax there (e.g. `isBlank()` from String class).

For compiling I use the `maven-compiler-plugin` (3.8.1) with the properties `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` each set to the value `1.8`.

If I compile `mvn clean` (`java -version` = `openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16`) it works fine.

Is the java version I give to the `maven-compiler-plugin` only informative? How can I make sure that I get an artifact that really works under Java 8. Do I need to have JDK 8 installed (i.e. `java -version` = `1.8`)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you use java 11 code if you intend it to work on a java 8 environment?

Comment: You should use `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` if using JDK9+... @Stultuske Why not ...it's easier...and also shows already if the code can be compiled with JDK11..

Comment: @Stultuske: I use Java 11, but had forgotten to change the properties. So I was wondering why this works.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks, that means only from 1.9 you can also do a syntax check.

Comment: No...syntax check has nothing to do with that... The source controls the syntax but it does not limit the methods from your jdk (earlier times used animal sniffer to check that)...today JDK9+ use release options..much easier and more reliable... So use JDK11 or JDK17 to build your app and control the target (version of generated class files) via `maven.compiler.release` property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maven.compiler.source` controls what syntax you can or can't use, but it doesn't limit what methods from the JDK the code can be compiled against. For that, you can use the `release` property. E.g:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>8</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```